# How can I handle modal dialogs with Behat and Goutte?

Tags: drupal, behat, gherkin

I'm testing a functionnality on a website that allows the user to fill a form. At a moment, the users needs to click on a button, which triggers an Ajax loaded modal that allows him to upload a file. However, when I trigger the button, Behat doesn't seem to "see" the modal window.

Maybe I should precise I'm in a Drupal 8 environment, but I don't know if this changed anything

Just so we're clear, I'm not talking about an alert, but this [kind of modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78sq8.jpg)

So far my tests looks like this:

```
Scenario: Creates a stage test with two sessions
    Given I am on "/user/login"
    And I fill in "user@user.com" for "name"
    And I fill in "password" for "pass"
    And I press "Log in"
    Then I should get a "200" HTTP response
    And I should see "User Name"
    When I go to "/node/add/stage"
    Then I should get a "200" HTTP response
    And I should see "Add content CISIA Stage"
    When I fill in "Test Cisia Stage" for "edit-title-0-value"
    And I press "Select files"
    Then I should see "Upload files" <-- fails
    And I should see "Click or drop files here to upload them" <-- gets ignored but is likely to fail too
```

I can't find anything modal-related on SO or Google in general, only about small message alerts, and people talk about objects or functions I don't have (such as `getWebDriver()`)

I also tried to find the modal's content by myself by doing so:

```
public function iShouldSeeAModalWindow() {

    $element = $this->getSession()->getPage();
    $modal = $element->find('css', sprintf('div:contains("%s")', 'Upload files'));

    if($modal) {
      exit('Yaaaay!');
    }

    else {
      throw new Exception("No modal found");
    }
}
```

However I got no luck so far.

What should I do?

Comment: You have an `iframe` and you need to switch to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an `iframe` and you need to switch to it.

Use something like this:

```
$this->getSession()->getDriver()->switchToIFrame('iframe_name');
```

I think you should also consider to write your scenario on a high level basis and also use page objects extension to avoid getting long scenarios that are hard to maintain and unreadable and also to reuse as much code as possible.

> Follow Behavior Driven Development methodology.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it took me a while to make it work but I now can find my elements inside my modal!

Comment: For the "long scenarios" I have no choice, this is a direct request from my work to make it as clear as possible for future people to maintain it later without knowing how to code